# Parsing JSON in PL/SQL

Tags: json, parsing, plsql

I am trying to get key names dynamically in PL/SQL (oracle).

This is my function

```
create FUNCTION GET_EXPRESSION_VALUES(data CLOB) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    action_api_response VARCHAR2(32767);
    data_value VARCHAR2(32767);
    json_obj            JSON_OBJECT_T ;
    keys                JSON_KEY_LIST;
    key                 VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    action_api_response := JSON_VALUE(data, '$.action_api_response');
    
    data_value := JSON_VALUE(action_api_response, '$.data');
    
    --WRITE_LOG_TABLE('EVALUTION_VALUES', data_value);

    json_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T(data_value);
    keys     := json_obj.GET_KEYS;

    FOR i IN 1..LEAST(keys.COUNT, 5) LOOP
        key := keys(i);
        WRITE_LOG_TABLE('EVALUTION_VALUES', key);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 'Success';

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
        RETURN 'ERROR';
END;
/
```

And this is the JSON

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "meta": {
        "responseType": "HashMap",
        "responseTypeFull": "java.util.HashMap"
    },
    "data": {
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC": "",
        "PATH": "",
        "ENVELOPE_MESSAGE": "",
        "INDEX_DOC": "",
        "ENVELOPE_NUMBER": "",
        "ADDRESS_BARCODE": "",
        "ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES": "",
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB": "",
        "ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL": "",
        "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV": "",
        "BARCODE": "",
        "PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP": "",
        "FILE_NAME": "",
        "DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK": "",
        "INSTANCE_ID": "",
        "D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR": "",
        "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID": "",
        "ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK": "",
        "COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM": "",
        "BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM": "",
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB": "",
        "DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP": "",
        "COMBINATION_ID_PREV": "",
        "PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX": "",
        "COMB_TYPE": "",
        "PRINT_STYLE": "",
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID": "",
        "CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER": "",
        "PATH_RAW": "",
        "SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX": "",
        "BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM": "",
        "FILE_EXTENSION": "",
        "CONTRACT_ID": "",
        "RUN_ID": "",
        "BRAND": "",
        "ORDER_BY": "",
        "RUN_START_DATE": "",
        "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV": "",
        "DOCUMENT_ID": "",
        "FLAG_FILE_SPLIT": "",
        "PATH_ARCHIVE": "",
        "SUB_BRAND": "",
        "STANDING_ORDER": "",
        "SOURCE_PATH": "",
        "JOB_ID": "",
        "PATH_PS": "",
        "DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM": "",
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID": "",
        "COMBINATION_TYPE": "",
        "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT": "",
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF": "",
        "PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX": "",
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV": "",
        "DOCUMENT_LABEL": "",
        "DOCUMENT_NAME": "",
        "FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE": "",
        "INDEX_ADRESS": "",
        "FILE_SUBDIRECTORY": "",
        "MAX_WAIT_DATE": "",
        "COMBINATION_ID": "",
        "LAST_IN_ENVELOPE": "",
        "COMBINATION_ID_NEXT": "",
        "PAGE_NUMBER": "",
        "PAGE_TYPE": "",
        "ENVELOPE_SIZE": "",
        "ENV_NUM": "",
        "FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC": "",
        "FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT": "",
        "PATH_SIGNED": "",
        "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC": "",
        "PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF": "",
        "FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME": "",
        "ENVELOPE_ACTION": "",
        "SORT_COL": "",
        "ID_BF_DOCUMENT": "",
        "CHANNEL_LABEL": "",
        "SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX": "",
        "BARCODE_VALUE": "",
        "SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER": ""
    }
}
```

This is how I call the function

```
DECLARE
KLOB CLOB;
BEGIN
KLOB := GET_EXPRESSION_VALUES('{"EVAL_FORMA":null,"action_api_response":"{\"code\":200,\"status\":\"OK\",\"meta\":{\"responseType\":\"HashMap\",\"responseTypeFull\":\"java.util.HashMap\"},\"data\":{\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC\":\"\",\"PATH\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_MESSAGE\":\"\",\"INDEX_DOC\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"ADDRESS_BARCODE\":\"\",\"ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB\":\"50\",\"ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL\":\"\",\"ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV\":\"\",\"BARCODE\":\"\",\"PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP\":\"\",\"FILE_NAME\":\"\",\"DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK\":\"\",\"INSTANCE_ID\":\"\",\"D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR\":\"\",\"CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK\":\"\",\"COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_ID_PREV\":\"\",\"PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX\":\"\",\"COMB_TYPE\":\"\",\"PRINT_STYLE\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID\":\"\",\"CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PATH_RAW\":\"\",\"SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX\":\"\",\"BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"FILE_EXTENSION\":\"\",\"CONTRACT_ID\":\"\",\"RUN_ID\":\"\",\"BRAND\":\"\",\"ORDER_BY\":\"\",\"RUN_START_DATE\":\"\",\"CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_ID\":\"\",\"FLAG_FILE_SPLIT\":\"\",\"PATH_ARCHIVE\":\"\",\"SUB_BRAND\":\"\",\"STANDING_ORDER\":\"\",\"SOURCE_PATH\":\"\",\"JOB_ID\":\"\",\"PATH_PS\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_TYPE\":\"\",\"ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF\":\"\",\"PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_LABEL\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_NAME\":\"\",\"FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE\":\"\",\"INDEX_ADRESS\":\"\",\"FILE_SUBDIRECTORY\":\"\",\"MAX_WAIT_DATE\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_ID\":\"\",\"LAST_IN_ENVELOPE\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_ID_NEXT\":\"\",\"PAGE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PAGE_TYPE\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_SIZE\":\"\",\"ENV_NUM\":\"\",\"FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC\":\"\",\"FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT\":\"\",\"PATH_SIGNED\":\"\",\"CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC\":\"\",\"PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF\":\"\",\"FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_ACTION\":\"\",\"SORT_COL\":\"\",\"ID_BF_DOCUMENT\":\"\",\"CHANNEL_LABEL\":\"\",\"SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX\":\"\",\"BARCODE_VALUE\":\"\",\"SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER\":\"\"}}","APPLICATION_USER":"multicom"}');
end;
```

The problem is, If I try to get keys from the top level, I get "code", "status", "meta", and "data". Now I want to get all the key names from data, but If I use the code written below nothing logs into the log_table. Not sure what's wrong, it should work because If I try to get single value then I get, so it's reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does exactly that. It gets keys, values, path of each of the elements:

```
create or replace TYPE       "JSON_ELEMENT_T"                                          as object (
   attr_level       number,
   attr_name        varchar2(255),
   attr_type        varchar2(30),
   attr_value       varchar2(255),
   attr_path        varchar2(255),
   parent_attr_path varchar2(255)
)
/

create or replace TYPE       "JSON_ELEMENT_CT"                                          as table of json_element_t
/

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_json( p_json IN CLOB ) RETURN json_element_ct IS
    l_parsed_json    apex_json.t_values;

    l_root_children  wwv_flow_t_varchar2;
    l_root_node      apex_json.t_value;

    l_p0             NUMBER := 0;
    l_p1             NUMBER := 0;
    l_p2             NUMBER := 0;
    l_p3             NUMBER := 0;
    l_p4             NUMBER := 0;

    l_result         json_element_ct := json_element_ct();

    FUNCTION replace_path( p_path IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN regexp_replace(
               regexp_replace(
                  regexp_replace(
                     regexp_replace(
                        regexp_replace( p_path, '%d', l_p0, 1, 1 ),
                        '%d', l_p1, 1, 1 ),
                     '%d', l_p2, 1, 1 ),
                  '%d', l_p3, 1, 1 ),
               '%d', l_p4, 1, 1 );
    END replace_path;

    PROCEDURE evaluate_node(
        p_prefix       IN VARCHAR2,
        p_node         IN apex_json.t_value,
        p_node_name    IN VARCHAR2,
        p_parent_name  IN VARCHAR2            DEFAULT NULL,
        p_level        IN NUMBER              DEFAULT 0,
        p_arraylevel   IN NUMBER              DEFAULT 1
    ) IS
      l_node          apex_json.t_value;
      l_node_children wwv_flow_t_varchar2;
      l_type          VARCHAR2(30);
      l_value         VARCHAR2(255);
    BEGIN
      IF p_node.kind = 2 THEN
          l_type := 'boolean';
          l_value := 'true';
      ELSIF p_node.kind = 3 THEN
          l_type := 'boolean';
          l_value := 'false';
      ELSIF p_node.kind = 4 THEN
          l_type := 'number';
          l_value := to_char( p_node.number_value );
      ELSIF p_node.kind = 5 THEN
          l_type := 'varchar2';
          l_value := p_node.varchar2_value;
      ELSIF p_node.kind = 7 THEN
          l_type := 'array';
          l_value := NULL;
          l_result.EXTEND(1);
          l_result( l_result.count ) := json_element_t ( p_level, nvl( p_node_name, '<no name>'), l_type, l_value, replace_path( p_prefix || p_node_name ), replace_path( p_parent_name ) );
          IF p_arraylevel = 1 THEN l_p0 := 0; END IF;
          IF p_arraylevel = 2 THEN l_p1 := 0; END IF;
          IF p_arraylevel = 3 THEN l_p2 := 0; END IF;
          IF p_arraylevel = 4 THEN l_p3 := 0; END IF;
          IF p_arraylevel = 5 THEN l_p4 := 0; END IF;
          FOR j IN 1 .. p_node.number_value loop
              IF p_arraylevel = 1 THEN l_p0 := l_p0 + 1; END IF;
              IF p_arraylevel = 2 THEN l_p1 := l_p1 + 1; END IF;
              IF p_arraylevel = 3 THEN l_p2 := l_p2 + 1; END IF;
              IF p_arraylevel = 4 THEN l_p3 := l_p3 + 1; END IF;
              IF p_arraylevel = 5 THEN l_p4 := l_p4 + 1; END IF;
              l_node := apex_json.get_value(
                  p_values => l_parsed_json,
                  p_path =>   p_prefix || p_node_name|| '[%d]',
                  p0 =>       l_p0,
                  p1 =>       l_p1,
                  p2 =>       l_p2,
                  p3 =>       l_p3,
                  p4 =>       l_p4 );
              evaluate_node(
                  p_prefix =>      p_prefix || p_node_name || '[%d]',
                  p_node =>        l_node,
                  p_node_name =>   NULL,
                  p_parent_name => p_prefix || p_node_name,
                  p_level =>       p_level + 1,
                  p_arraylevel =>  p_arraylevel + 1 );
          END loop;
      ELSIF p_node.kind = 6 THEN
          l_type := 'object';
          l_value := NULL;
          l_result.EXTEND(1);
          l_result( l_result.count ) := json_element_t ( p_level, nvl( p_node_name, '<no name>'), l_type, l_value, replace_path( p_prefix || p_node_name ), replace_path( p_parent_name ) );
          l_node_children := apex_json.get_members(
              p_values => l_parsed_json,
              p_path =>   p_prefix || p_node_name,
              p0 =>       l_p0,
              p1 =>       l_p1,
              p2 =>       l_p2,
              p3 =>       l_p3,
              p4 =>       l_p4 );
          IF l_node_children IS NOT NULL THEN
              FOR i IN 1 .. l_node_children.count LOOP
                  l_node := apex_json.get_value(
                       p_values => l_parsed_json,
                       p_path =>   p_prefix || p_node_name || '.' || l_node_children( i ),
                       p0 =>       l_p0,
                       p1 =>       l_p1,
                       p2 =>       l_p2,
                       p3 =>       l_p3,
                       p4 =>       l_p4 );
                   evaluate_node(
                       p_prefix =>      p_prefix || p_node_name || '.',
                       p_node =>        l_node,
                       p_node_name =>   l_node_children( i ),
                       p_parent_name => p_prefix || p_node_name,
                       p_level =>       p_level + 1,
                        p_arraylevel =>  p_arraylevel );
               END loop;
           END IF;
      END IF;
      IF p_node.kind IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5 ) THEN
          l_result.EXTEND( 1 );
          l_result( l_result.count ) := json_element_t ( p_level, nvl( p_node_name, '<no name>'), l_type, l_value, replace_path( p_prefix || p_node_name ), replace_path( p_parent_name ) );
      END IF;
    END evaluate_node;
  BEGIN
    apex_json.parse( l_parsed_json, p_json );
    l_root_children := apex_json.get_members( p_values => l_parsed_json, p_path => '.' );

    l_result.EXTEND( 1 );
    l_result( l_result.count ) := json_element_t ( NULL, '<root>', 'object', NULL, '<root>', NULL );

    IF l_root_children IS NOT NULL THEN

         FOR i IN 1 .. l_root_children.count loop

             l_root_node := apex_json.get_value(
                 p_values => l_parsed_json,
                 p_path =>   l_root_children( i ) );

             evaluate_node(
                 p_prefix =>      NULL,
                 p_node =>        l_root_node,
                 p_node_name =>   l_root_children( i ),
                 p_parent_name => '<root>' );
         END loop;
    END IF;
    RETURN l_result;
  END parse_json;
/


DECLARE
  l_json_nodes_ct JSON_ELEMENT_CT;
BEGIN
  l_json_nodes_ct := parse_json('{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "meta": {
        "responseType": "HashMap",
        "responseTypeFull": "java.util.HashMap"
    },
    "data": {
        "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC": "",
        "PATH": "",
        "ENVELOPE_MESSAGE": ""
    }
}');
  FOR r IN 1 .. l_json_nodes_ct.COUNT LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(l_json_nodes_ct(r).attr_name);
  END LOOP;
  
END;

-----
attr_level:     
attr_name:     <root>
attr_type:     object
attr_value:     
attr_path:     <root>
-----
attr_level:     0
attr_name:     code
attr_type:     number
attr_value:     200
attr_path:     code
-----
attr_level:     0
attr_name:     status
attr_type:     varchar2
attr_value:     OK
attr_path:     status

etc...
```

Credits go to @Carsten Czarski